# Wildfly Greeter quickstart project

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wildfly-8

The `'greeter'` is a quickstart project in **WildFly 8** to demonstrate basic hibernate database and JPA functionality as a tutorial. In the project, I don't understand when and how the "USERS" database is created in H2 database. These are two relevant files for database creation and setting:

1. META-INF/persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="primary">
        <!-- If you are running in a production environment, add a managed 
            data source, this example data source is just for development and testing! -->
        <!-- The datasource is deployed as WEB-INF/greeter-quickstart-ds.xml, 
            you can find it in the source at src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/greeter-quickstart-ds.xml -->
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/GreeterQuickstartDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

2. WEB-INF/greeter-quickstart-ds.xml

```
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">
    <!-- The datasource is bound into JNDI at this location. We reference 
        this in META-INF/persistence.xml -->
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/GreeterQuickstartDS"
        pool-name="greeter-quickstart" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:greeter-quickstart;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
        <driver>h2</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>sa</user-name>
            <password>sa</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
</datasources>
```

3. /wildfly-greeter/src/main/resources/import.sql

   `INSERT INTO USERS (ID, USERNAME, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES (-1, 'jdoe', 'John', 'Doe');`

   `INSERT INTO USERS (ID, USERNAME, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES (-2, 'emuster', 'Erika',   'Mustermann');`

By default, the H2 database system does not come with a USERS database, which is used by the demo. So how the "USERS" is created in this demo project? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

USERS database is automatically reated when you run the project bacause of the following setting in `persistence.xml`:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
```

Comment: But there is no any mentioning of "USERS"？ Is that because hibernate auto create this one? Does it also create other databases by default with this property specification?

Comment: This setting creates all tables that are represented by the entity classes in your application (including USERS).

Answer (score 1):

The database is set up by Hibernate at deployment time. To build the database schema, Hibernate scans through all relevant files, not just XML files, but also classes, to get the information it needs and that is where the table ***Users*** comes from.

Here is the exact code from the `greeter` quickstart example that is responsible for the ***Users*** table:

```
@Entity
// User is a keyword in some SQL dialects!
@Table(name="Users")
public class User {
... etc.
```

So, there it is, they just called it ***Users*** with a plural '*s*' to avoid conflicts with the DBMS of your choice.